# Rails Mysql sort by one of associated tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models with relationships:

```
User (id, email)
SellerProfile (user_id, name)
BuyerProfile (user_id, name)
```

User may have one of associated tables.
I am sorting results by name but name can come from `seller_profile` or `buyer_profile` tables.

I build it with two conditional subqueries but i was looking for getting this in one request.

I tried to play with joins but it didnt worked because its never known if user has associated `seller_profile` or `buyer_profile`.

anyone tried similar ?

Comment: You need to use LEFT JOINs. Please read a tutorial on how to use that in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
User.left_joins(:seller_profile, :buyer_profile).order("COALESCE(seller_profiles.name, buyer_profiles.name)")
```

I would reconsider your database design if you are facing such issues though. Do you need separate tables? Can you extract some common table (e.g. `Profile`)?